# How to list the size and path of all files in the working directory by using find?

Tags: files, find

Now I'm trying to list the size and path by using find

This is what I have done

```
root@MSI:~/breakfast# find; du
.
./practice.py
./helloworld.txt
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
./messy
./messy/read file
./messy/file3.txt
./messy/open file
./exercise.py
16      ./messy
32      .
```

I wonder why there are only 2 size files that appears.
I mean I want each file to be separated, but I don't know what to do. If anyone have a better way to do please share it to me.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `find` list the 1st set of files in your list
- `du` the 2 lines at the end: 1 for the subdirectory, and 1 for a total size.

A generic method of doing what you want is:

```
find . -exec du -a {} +
```

and if you want to sort by size descending use:

```
find . -exec du -a {} + | sort -n -r | less
```

- add `-type f` to only show files and no directories or `-type d` for only directories.

Comment: Another that I use. ` find /mnt/data -name "Zsync*" | xargs ls -oAHd
`